# Неправильно работает сортировка пузырьком с флажком

Tags: c#, алгоритм, пузырьковая-сортировка

В общем, нашел в интернете реализацию сортировки пузырьком с флажком, но что-то в ней не так, вроде как итераций должно выходить меньше, а выходит больше, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так и по возможности помогите исправить)

```
    int temp;
    int counter1 = 0;
    int[] arr = { 5, 45, 2, 345, 67, 31, 11, 98, 67, 1 };
    bool flag = false;
    //Это код пузырька с флажком
        do
        {
            flag = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
            {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                    flag = true;
                }
                ++counter1;
            }


        } while (flag);


//Это код обычного пузырька
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; ++j)
            {
                if (arr[i] > arr[j])
                {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
                ++counter1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `что-то в ней не так, вроде как итераций должно выходить меньше, а выходит больше` как это понимать?

Comment: Ой, не уточнил, это по сравнению с обычной сортировкой пузырьком

Comment: если вы сравниваете два алгоритма, то и приводите код для двух алгоритмов. Если вы сраниваете метрики, то приводите их в числах.

Comment: Исправил, добавил код второго алгоритма

Comment: ну, для начала, второй алгоритм это не "пузырек", а "поиск минимума". Поэтому результаты, ожидаемо, разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Количество итераций в вашем первом алгоритме зависит от данных. Попробуйте запустить его на отсортированном массиве.

Количество итераций во втором аогоритме зависит только от величины массива и не зависит от данных в массиве.

Почему в первом алгоритме итераций может быть больше, чем во втором? Потому что в первом алгоритме вы меняете только соседние элементы местами. Поэтому, если минимальный элемент стоит в конце, ему надо пройти 9 разменов с соседями, пока он добератся до начала. Во втором алгоритме вы меняете любой с любым, и минимальному элементу нужен только 1 размен, чтобы встать на свое место.

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Естественно будет больше, так как в этом алгоритме много раз просматривается весь массив до тех пор, пока остается возможность обмена двух элементов.

Если вы имели в виду оптимизацию пузырька, то будет вот так

```
int temp;

        int[] arr = { 5, 45, 2, 345, 67, 31, 11, 98, 67, 1 };
        bool flag = true;
        int i = 0;
        int n = 10;
        //Это код пузырька с флажком
        while (flag)
        {
            flag = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                {

                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                    flag = true;
                }

            }
            i = i + 1;

        }
```

Здесь мы используем 2 соображения

1) после i-ой итерации внешнего цикла i последних элементов уже находятся на своих местах в отсортированном порядке, поэтому нет необходимости производить их сравнения друг с другом

2) если после выполнения внутреннего цикла не произошло ни одного обмена, то массив уже отсортирован

Comment: Странно, итераций стало всего 7, и массив на выходе не отсортирован

Comment: Поправил. Не туда поставил инкремент i.